# Can't set featured image for custom post-type

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, custom-post-type

I don't know whats happening but suddenly some things started to disappear from the admin panel. I have a custom post type for ads and they have support for thumbnail, meaning:

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail')
```

But today when i was trying to insert a new ad the featured image / thumbnail didn't show up so i could select an image from media. It's very strange.

I also can't see the image from previous ad's, but this only in the admin panel, they are perfectly ok in the "Front End".

Update -

I also tried to include this functions at some init hook and didn't work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_pub' );

function create_post_pub()
{
  // ....

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'publicidade' ) );
    add_theme_support( 'thumbnail', array( 'post', 'publicidade' ) );


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have `add_theme_support('post_thumbnails')` in your theme's functions.php ?

Comment: No, but i never had and it was ok. I also tried to put that in functions and didn't work.

Comment: add this in a function and hook that function on init

Comment: @wordpresser didn't work. I'll update my question and provide that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I can't believe i spent so much time figuring this out, i thought it was a theme's problem sort of. My client ended up unchecking the "featured image" checkbox from the "screen options" at the top right corner.